# Why does my send port not working in biztalk after poll operation from sql?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am using BizTalk 2013 version. I am facing an issue. I have a simple orchestration: I do poll from a SQL database every 30 seconds and then I have my message called PollingMessage. Then I need to transform this message into a new one (TestMessage) with a mapping. After this transformation I need to send my new message TestMessage to a port (TestPort) and then the old message PollingMessage to another port (SaveMessagePort). I built the project, deployed it and then I done the bindings through Administration Tool. When I start the application I successfully see my PollingMessage to the folder bound to SaveMessagePort but I can't see the TestMessage.

I don't understand why. Can you help me?

Comment: What filters have you set on the send ports?  Is your map executing in the Receive Port or the Send Port or Orchestration?  Or have you bound port send ports to the Orchestration?  Have you used the BizTalk admin console to check the steps executed in the Orchestration and checked for suspended messages?

Comment: Hi Dijkgraaf, thanks for replying. The map is executing in Orchestration and I bound send ports in admin console. I think I know what the problem is now. The problem are filters because I filter by BTS.MessageType but I used PassThruReceive pipeline instead of XMLReceive. I know this is the problem because I am reading logs application and it say it cannot find the property of filtering. Now I changed the pipeline to XMLReceive and now I am getting another error -  "Exception type: ServiceCreationException, Additional error information: Value does not fall within the expected range."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is solved. There was something wrong with my schema, now everything is working like it should.